# SQL SERVER 2008 data Insertion Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

```
CREATE TABLE GroovyExps_Tgt
      (EMPNO                SMALLINT,
       FIRSTNAME            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       MIDINIT              CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
       LASTNAME             VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
       SALARY_INT           INT,
       SALARY_Decimal       DECIMAL,
       SALARY_Numeric       NUMERIC,
       SALARY_FLOAT         FLOAT(9), 
       SALARY_MONEY         MONEY,
       SALARY_SMALLMONEY    SMALLMONEY,        
       BIRTHDATE            DATETIME,       
       HIREDATE_DATETIME    DATETIME,
       JOIN_TIME            TIME,
       JOINTIME             DATETIME) 


insert into GroovyExps_Tgt 
values(000010, 'CHRISTINE', 'I', 'HAAS', 52750, 52750.45, 52750.45000045, 52750.45454, 
       52750, 52750, '1980-08-22', '2014-08-22 10:00:00.000000', '16:00', '2014-08-22 10:00:00.000000')
```

Error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What should I do to successfully insert data into this table?

Comment: Probbaly a time value could not be converted having so much zeros

Comment: Why do you store the salary in so many ways? Why not store it as money and be fine with it?

Comment: If you want to erase your question, use the delete function. Please don't deface existing questions. Your edit has been [rolled back.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27013193/revisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS SQL Server supports `Datetime` upto 1000 miliseconds. these queries will explain problem :

```
select CAST('2014-08-22 10:00:00.000000' as datetime)
select CAST('2014-08-22 10:00:00.000' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the time part of the data you are trying to insert under the `BIRTHDATE` column.

Try inserting `'1980-08-22 00:00:00.00'` instead of just `1980-08-22` if you don't have a time part for that value since the `datetime` data type requires both date and time values.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **3** Zeros.. It will work..

```
insert into TempGroovyExps_Tgt values(
000010,'CHRISTINE','I','HAAS',52750,52750.45,52750.45000045,
52750.45454,52750,52750,'1980-08-22','2014-08-22 10:00:00.000',
'16:00','2014-08-22 10:00:00.000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into GroovyExps_Tgt values(000010,'CHRISTINE','I','HAAS',52750,52750.45,52750.45000045,52750.45454,52750,52750,'1980-08-22 10:00:00','2014-08-22 10:00:00','16:00','2014-08-22 10:00:00')
```

Replaced `'1980-08-22'` with `'1980-08-22 10:00:00'` in **BIRTHDATE** column. Meaning you were trying to insert the **date** in **datetime** datatype with leading zeros(.000000).

**Update:**
Yes you are right but it should take sense.

The probably the reason was with the leading `.000000` zeros in values for example '2014-08-22 10:00:00.000000', simply ignore it as '2014-08-22 10:00:00'.

Comment: Please **explain** what you've changed - and why!

Comment: I think, there should not be any problem in inserting `date` value into a `datetime` column. so this is not the reason.